# How to show series dataLabels inside the Highchart pyramid in angular

Tags: angular, highcharts

I am using Highchart pyramid in angular, Now its labels are showing in the right side of the below attached image. As i want to show series dataLabels inside the Highchart pyramid, i attached the below code i am using to retrieve Highchart pyramid .

How can I solve this?

[image]

```
public loadSevirtychart(data): any {
   const that = this;
   that.chartOptions2 = {
       chart: {
           type: "pyramid",
       },
       title: {
           text: "",
       },
       plotOptions: {
           series: {
               dataLabels: {
                   enabled: true,
                   format: "({point.x:,.0f})",
                   allowOverlap: false,
                   connectorPadding: 0,
                   distance: 10,
                   softConnector: true,
                   x: 0,
                   connectorShape: "fixedOffset",
                   crookDistance: "70%"
               },
               showInLegend: true,
               cursor: "pointer",
               point: {
                   events: {
                       click(event) {
                           that.drilldownseveritychart(this.id, this.name);
                       },
                   },
               },
           },
       },
       tooltip: {
           formatter() {
               const val = this.point.x;
               return "<b>" + this.point.name + "</b>: " + val + "";
           },
       },
       credits: {
           enabled: false,
       },
       legend: {
           layout: "horizontal",
           verticalAlign: "bottom",
           align: "center",
           itemWidth: 85,
           symbolWidth: 8,
           symbolHight: 6,
           floating: false,
           borderWidth: 0,
           backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
           shadow: false,
           itemStyle: {
               font: "8pt Trebuchet MS, Verdana, sans-serif",
               color: "#A0A0A0",
           },
       },
       series: [{
           name: "Count",
           data,
       }],
   };
}
```

Comment: Try to use `distance: -50` in pixels inside datalabels

Comment: I tried it its not working,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `dataLabels.inside = true` (Highcharts version 7.1.2 and higher):

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      inside: true,
      align: "center",
      verticalAlign: "middle"
    }
  }
}
```

**Demo:**

- https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-spgl0

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SeriesPieDataLabelsOptionsObject#inside
- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SeriesPieDataLabelsOptionsObject#align
- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SeriesPieDataLabelsOptionsObject#verticalAlign

Comment: Thanks its worked perfectly..
In my scenario i am using "7.0.1" version that is the issue not working for me
For the latest version "7.1.2" its working 
thanks for support and response....